# Android app can write data on Nexus S but not on samsung S2 on "/sdcard/filename" path?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

1. i have given required permission :
   `<uses-permission                                    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
2. hard-coded the path as `"/sdcard/filename"`.

I guess Nexus don't have external SD support but S2 has, that I think might cause a problem in getting the path. How should I handle such a case gracefully?

Comment: "hard-coded the path as "/sdcard/filename"." -- do not do that. For starters, it has been wrong for a couple of years. As glethien notes, use appropriate methods on `Environment` to get at a directory on external storage.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Samsung S2 external memory card is not on that location, so you should use the method provided by glethien which will work on all devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each Android Device you can get the path to the external storage like this

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

I've a Nexus device and it works - also on my old milestone

Comment: I remember how I wanted to rip my head off when I discovered that for some devices the path is mnt/sdcard and for another is sdcard/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example usage to create your own apps directory:**

You should always check to see if the SDcard is available first because it could be mounted/teathered to a computer or be removed from the device.

```
private void SetDirectory() {
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File dbDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/yourAppName/whatever/");
            myDirectory.mkdirs();// Have the object build the directory

        } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {

            //TODO Make some kind of allert or Toast to warn/notify the user that the SDcard is needed.
        }

    }
```

You can use the `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)` method to check if the card is available anywhere within your application.

Comment: thanks to all for sharing this nice info. I am going to try it.